# replaceAll using regular expression with colon with dynamic string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have question regarding replaceAll with regEx. I have searched many posts and tried different regEx but I am not getting desired result. My question is I have large String in that I have some line like this:
actioncode : abcdefg and resultcode :dynamicText some normal text here : asdwesd

Here I want to replace ":dynamicText" to ": dynamicText" but I will not know dynamicText. "dynamicText" will keep on changing. I have tried using Java:

```java
String hef = "actioncode : abcdefg and resultcode :dynamicText some normal text here : asdwesd";
System.out.println("String is  =>"+hef);
System.out.println("Replaced string is \n"+hef.replaceAll(" :[A-Za-z]", " : "));
```

**Output:**

String is  =>actioncode : abcdefg and resultcode **:dynamicText** some normal text here : asdwesd

Replaced string is
actioncode : abcdefg and resultcode **: ynamicText** some normal text here : asdwesd

If we observe the replaced value --> ": ynamicText" in this first character of DynamicText is removed. I don't want to strip or remove first character of DynamicText

Even I have tried with :

```
hef.trim().replaceAll(" :\\W", " : ")
hef.replaceAll("\\s:[A-Za-z]", " : ")
```

But I am not getting desired output. Can anyone please help me to write correct regular expression?

Comment: `replaceAll(":(?=\\p{L})", "$0 ")`? `replaceAll(":([A-Za-z])", ": $1")`?

Answer (score 0):

`$1` stands for the capture group reference `([A-Za-z])`, to keep the first letter you should use this reference in the replacement parameter.

Try this:

```
String hef = "actioncode : abcdefg and resultcode :dynamicText some normal text here : asdwesd"; 
System.out.println("String is =>"+hef); 
hef = hef.replaceAll(" :([A-Za-z])", " : $1");
System.out.println("Replaced string is \n"+ hef);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got expected result.

Comment: Hi @Krishna glad it helped, would you consider accepting/upvoting the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Or just `hef = hef.replaceAll(" :(?=[A-Za-z])", " : ");`